# C# SHGetFileInfo get File properties

Tags: c#, listview

I'm adding items (files) to Listview with icons and file types, using SHGetFileInfo. I want to add file creation time & file size from same function too. According to MSDN I could extract these from SHGFI_ATTR_SPECIFIED flag, but I haven't done anything like that so far, so I'm kind of lost... Here is what I tried so far:

```
foreach (FileInfo file in dir.EnumerateFiles())
{

IntPtr file_properties = SHGetFileInfo(file.FullName, 0,
ref shfi, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(shfi),
SHGFI_ATTR_SPECIFIED | SHGFI_TYPENAME | SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME | 
SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX 
| SHGFI_SMALLICON |SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES);

lvi = new ListViewItem();
lvi.Tag = file.FullName;
lvi.Text = shfi.szDisplayName;
lvi.SubItems.Add(file.LastWriteTime.ToShortDateString() //I would like to add these with SHGetFileInfo if possible
 + " " + file.LastWriteTime.ToShortTimeString());
lvi.SubItems.Add(shfi.szTypeName);
lvi.SubItems.Add(shfi.dwAttributes.ToString()); //this returns 0
lvi.ImageIndex = shfi.iIcon;
Listivew1.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

Comment: You have conflicting `SHGFI` flags. If you specify `SHGFI_SMALLICON`, you aslo have to include `SHGFI_ICON` and `SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX`. But, if you include `SHGFI_ICON`, you can't include `SHGFI_ATTR_SPECIFIED`. Then you have not set the `dwFileAttributes` (secon parameter of `SHGetFileInfo()`). This specifies what kind of file attributes must be included. 0 = none, not all, because you have included `SHGFI_ATTR_SPECIFIED` which means *return the attributes specified by `dwFileAttributes`*. You should use `SHGFI_ATTRIBUTES = 0x000000800` instead. In this case, `dwFileAttributes = 0` means `All`

Comment: @Jimi, yes, I've tried that too, but It only returns me some number, not file attribute I want. Can I even get desired attributes from this function  - that is file creation time & file size, same as in Windows Explorer ?

Comment: No. The [SHFILEINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759792(v=vs.85).aspx) structure returns, with the `dwAttributes` member, a [SFGAO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762589(v=vs.85).aspx) combination of file attributes. You have to use [GetFileAttributesEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364946(v=vs.85).aspx) for File date references. But of couse you're better off with a .NET `FileInfo` class for those details.

Comment: @Jimi, thanks, that was my question actually. Problem is that when adding items with subitems in Listview everything slows a bit when working with network drives and bigger directories, and SHGetFileInto doesn't have problems with that. GetFileAttributeEX extracts only file dates, but as you mentioned FileInfo is better. Though that still leaves me with attribute of file sizes, which I currently extract from ShellFolder object, but that seriously slows down adding items. I was hoping SHGetFileInfo could get me all - since It's working fine and fast for icons, displayname & file type attribute.

Comment: What can slow down the procedure, is adding one file info at the time. You should do it in batch. That is, get all the informations you need, then use the ListView `BeginUpdate()` `EndUpdate()` and add all elements in one go. Network drives will be slower in any case.

Comment: @Jimi, I haven't provided that in my question code, but I actually do that, and even more - I add all new ListViewItems in a List<ListViewItem> and then add them all to ListView at once using Items.AddRange(items.ToArray()). But still, doing debugging checks, all attributes (Listview subitems) - name,file type, file creation & file size considerably slows down Listview in bigger directories. SHGetFileinfo flag **SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES** speeds up everything a lot, so I was hoping to obtain all file details doing so. Unfortunally I cannot, I'll have to settle with this.